# Given a data frame in JSON format, how can I automatically assign colors to variables in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, shiny

I have been learning from D3.js to build an app in shiny. The shiny app sends a JSON structure to the Javascript code. The Javascript code runs and creates a [double vertical graph].(http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/cd80ab54c52f80c4d84cad0ba9da72c2).

The JSON data after processing is as follows. This is a reproducible example

```
var data=[['Lite','CA',16,0],
['Small','CA',1278,4],
['Medium','CA',27,0],
['Plus','CA',58,0],
['Grand','CA',1551,15],
['Elite','CA',141,0],
['Lite','AZ',5453,35],
['Small','AZ',683,1],
['Medium','AZ',862,0],
['Grand','AZ',6228,30],
['Lite','AL',15001,449],
['Small','AL',527,3],
['Medium','AL',836,0],
['Plus','AL',28648,1419],
['Grand','AL',3,0],
['Lite','CO',13,0],
['Small','CO',396,0],
['Medium','CO',362,0],
['Plus','CO',78,10],
['Grand','CO',2473,32],
['Elite','CO',2063,64],
['Medium','DE',203,0],
['Grand','DE',686,2],
['Elite','DE',826,0],
['Lite','KS',1738,110],
['Small','KS',12925,13],
['Medium','KS',15413,0],
['Small','GA',2166,2],
['Medium','GA',86,0],
['Plus','GA',348,3],
['Grand','GA',4244,18],
['Elite','GA',1536,1],
['Small','IA',351,0],
['Grand','IA',405,1],
['Small','IL',914,1],
['Medium','IL',127,0],
['Grand','IL',1470,7],
['Elite','IL',516,1],
['Lite','IN',43,0],
['Small','IN',667,1],
['Medium','IN',172,0],
['Plus','IN',149,1],
['Grand','IN',1380,5],
['Elite','IN',791,23],
['Small','FL',1,0],
['Grand','FL',1,0],
['Small','MD',1070,1],
['Grand','MD',1171,2],
['Elite','MD',33,0],
['Plus','TX',1,0],
['Small','MS',407,0],
['Medium','MS',3,0],
['Grand','MS',457,2],
['Elite','MS',20,0],
['Small','NC',557,0],
['Medium','NC',167,0],
['Plus','NC',95,1],
['Grand','NC',1090,5],
['Elite','NC',676,6],
['Lite','NM',1195,99],
['Small','NM',350,3],
['Medium','NM',212,0],
['Grand','NM',1509,8],
['Lite','NV',3899,389],
['Small','NV',147,0],
['Medium','NV',455,0],
['Plus','NV',1,1],
['Grand','NV',4100,16],
['Lite','OH',12,0],
['Small','OH',634,2],
['Medium','OH',749,0],
['Plus','OH',119,1],
['Grand','OH',3705,19],
['Elite','OH',3456,25],
['Small','PA',828,2],
['Medium','PA',288,0],
['Plus','PA',141,0],
['Grand','PA',2625,7],
['Elite','PA',1920,10],
['Small','SC',1146,2],
['Medium','SC',212,0],
['Plus','SC',223,4],
['Grand','SC',1803,6],
['Elite','SC',761,8],
['Small','TN',527,0],
['Medium','TN',90,0],
['Grand','TN',930,4],
['Elite','TN',395,1],
['Lite','ME',7232,58],
['Small','ME',1272,0],
['Medium','ME',1896,0],
['Plus','ME',1,0],
['Grand','ME',10782,33],
['Elite','ME',1911,3],
['Small','VA',495,0],
['Medium','VA',32,0],
['Plus','VA',7,0],
['Grand','VA',1557,12],
['Elite','VA',24,0],
['Small','WA',460,1],
['Plus','WA',88,3],
['Grand','WA',956,3],
['Small','WV',232,0],
['Medium','WV',71,0],
['Grand','WV',575,2],
['Elite','WV',368,3]
];
```

The code to visualize the data is a follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
text{
    font-size:12px;
}
.mainBars rect{
  shape-rendering: auto;
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  stroke-opacity: 0;
}
.subBars{
    shape-rendering:crispEdges;
}
.edges{
    stroke:none;
    fill-opacity:0.5;
}
.header{
    text-anchor:middle;
    font-size:16px;
}
line{
    stroke:grey;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data=[['Lite','CA',16,0],
['Small','CA',1278,4],
['Medium','CA',27,0],
['Plus','CA',58,0],
['Grand','CA',1551,15],
['Elite','CA',141,0],
['Lite','AZ',5453,35],
['Small','AZ',683,1],
['Medium','AZ',862,0],
['Grand','AZ',6228,30],
['Lite','AL',15001,449],
['Small','AL',527,3],
['Medium','AL',836,0],
['Plus','AL',28648,1419],
['Grand','AL',3,0],
['Lite','CO',13,0],
['Small','CO',396,0],
['Medium','CO',362,0],
['Plus','CO',78,10],
['Grand','CO',2473,32],
['Elite','CO',2063,64],
['Medium','DE',203,0],
['Grand','DE',686,2],
['Elite','DE',826,0],
['Lite','KS',1738,110],
['Small','KS',12925,13],
['Medium','KS',15413,0],
['Small','GA',2166,2],
['Medium','GA',86,0],
['Plus','GA',348,3],
['Grand','GA',4244,18],
['Elite','GA',1536,1],
['Small','IA',351,0],
['Grand','IA',405,1],
['Small','IL',914,1],
['Medium','IL',127,0],
['Grand','IL',1470,7],
['Elite','IL',516,1],
['Lite','IN',43,0],
['Small','IN',667,1],
['Medium','IN',172,0],
['Plus','IN',149,1],
['Grand','IN',1380,5],
['Elite','IN',791,23],
['Small','FL',1,0],
['Grand','FL',1,0],
['Small','MD',1070,1],
['Grand','MD',1171,2],
['Elite','MD',33,0],
['Plus','TX',1,0],
['Small','MS',407,0],
['Medium','MS',3,0],
['Grand','MS',457,2],
['Elite','MS',20,0],
['Small','NC',557,0],
['Medium','NC',167,0],
['Plus','NC',95,1],
['Grand','NC',1090,5],
['Elite','NC',676,6],
['Lite','NM',1195,99],
['Small','NM',350,3],
['Medium','NM',212,0],
['Grand','NM',1509,8],
['Lite','NV',3899,389],
['Small','NV',147,0],
['Medium','NV',455,0],
['Plus','NV',1,1],
['Grand','NV',4100,16],
['Lite','OH',12,0],
['Small','OH',634,2],
['Medium','OH',749,0],
['Plus','OH',119,1],
['Grand','OH',3705,19],
['Elite','OH',3456,25],
['Small','PA',828,2],
['Medium','PA',288,0],
['Plus','PA',141,0],
['Grand','PA',2625,7],
['Elite','PA',1920,10],
['Small','SC',1146,2],
['Medium','SC',212,0],
['Plus','SC',223,4],
['Grand','SC',1803,6],
['Elite','SC',761,8],
['Small','TN',527,0],
['Medium','TN',90,0],
['Grand','TN',930,4],
['Elite','TN',395,1],
['Lite','ME',7232,58],
['Small','ME',1272,0],
['Medium','ME',1896,0],
['Plus','ME',1,0],
['Grand','ME',10782,33],
['Elite','ME',1911,3],
['Small','VA',495,0],
['Medium','VA',32,0],
['Plus','VA',7,0],
['Grand','VA',1557,12],
['Elite','VA',24,0],
['Small','WA',460,1],
['Plus','WA',88,3],
['Grand','WA',956,3],
['Small','WV',232,0],
['Medium','WV',71,0],
['Grand','WV',575,2],
['Elite','WV',368,3]
];
var color ={Elite:"#3366CC", Grand:"#DC3912",  Lite:"#FF9900", Medium:"#109618", Plus:"#990099", Small:"#0099C6"};
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 960).attr("height", 800);

svg.append("text").attr("x",250).attr("y",70)
    .attr("class","header").text("Sales Attempt");

svg.append("text").attr("x",750).attr("y",70)
    .attr("class","header").text("Sales");

var g =[svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(150,100)")
        ,svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(650,100)")];

var bp=[ viz.bP()
        .data(data)
        .min(12)
        .pad(1)
        .height(600)
        .width(200)
        .barSize(35)
        .fill(d=>color[d.primary])      
    ,viz.bP()
        .data(data)
        .value(d=>d[3])
        .min(12)
        .pad(1)
        .height(600)
        .width(200)
        .barSize(35)
        .fill(d=>color[d.primary])
];

[0,1].forEach(function(i){
    g[i].call(bp[i])

    g[i].append("text").attr("x",-50).attr("y",-8).style("text-anchor","middle").text("Channel");
    g[i].append("text").attr("x", 250).attr("y",-8).style("text-anchor","middle").text("State");

    g[i].append("line").attr("x1",-100).attr("x2",0);
    g[i].append("line").attr("x1",200).attr("x2",300);

    g[i].append("line").attr("y1",610).attr("y2",610).attr("x1",-100).attr("x2",0);
    g[i].append("line").attr("y1",610).attr("y2",610).attr("x1",200).attr("x2",300);

    g[i].selectAll(".mainBars")
        .on("mouseover",mouseover)
        .on("mouseout",mouseout);

    g[i].selectAll(".mainBars").append("text").attr("class","label")
        .attr("x",d=>(d.part=="primary"? -30: 30))
        .attr("y",d=>+6)
        .text(d=>d.key)
        .attr("text-anchor",d=>(d.part=="primary"? "end": "start"));

    g[i].selectAll(".mainBars").append("text").attr("class","perc")
        .attr("x",d=>(d.part=="primary"? -100: 80))
        .attr("y",d=>+6)
        .text(function(d){ return d3.format("0.0%")(d.percent)})
        .attr("text-anchor",d=>(d.part=="primary"? "end": "start"));
});

function mouseover(d){
    [0,1].forEach(function(i){
        bp[i].mouseover(d);

        g[i].selectAll(".mainBars").select(".perc")
        .text(function(d){ return d3.format("0.0%")(d.percent)});
    });
}
function mouseout(d){
    [0,1].forEach(function(i){
        bp[i].mouseout(d);

        g[i].selectAll(".mainBars").select(".perc")
        .text(function(d){ return d3.format("0.0%")(d.percent)});
    });
}
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to replace the line `var color ={Elite:"#3366CC", Grand:"#DC3912",  Lite:"#FF9900", Medium:"#109618", Plus:"#990099", Small:"#0099C6"};`
 with a much more flexible statement? This line should assign colors to the variables dynamically as the data that is being exported from shiny is not static. Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know "shiny", but some ideas on the `color` variable are to assign the colors with function calls back to "shiny"

```
color.Elite = shinyGetEliteColor();
```

This of course assumes your page can call back to shiny.  But, assuming shiny built your page for you, what you have already should be a color object with shiny generated values.

If you want it to be more dynamic than that, you use a direct callback where the color array is referenced.

```
.fill(d=>color[d.primary])
```

...would become...

```
.fill(d=>shinyGetColor(d.primary))
```

Which could be slow since a color might be gotten multiple times. Again, this assumes you can write such a callback accepting a value like 'Elite' or 'Small'.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do what you want (*"...this line should assign colors to the variables dynamically as the data that is being exported from shiny is not static"*). I believe the simpler one is using an ordinal scale:

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
```

The nice thing about ordinal scales is that you don't need to set the domain. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleOrdinal):

> Setting the domain on an ordinal scale is optional if the unknown value is implicit (the default). In this case, the domain will be inferred implicitly from usage by assigning each unique value passed to the scale a new value from the range.

Therefore, new values will be assigned new colours, in a first-come, first-served basis.

Then, just do:

```
.fill(d=>color(d.primary))
```

Here is your updated bl.ocks with those changes: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/c96b317db952dc5ebeec2eb301da5483/6af28383cf1daee5bad783c86c4f5f6be805f74f

As the colour range I'm using `d3.schemeCategory20`. It contains 20 colours, so you can have 20 different variables (if you have more than that, the 21st variable will have the same colour of the 1st, the 22nd the same colour of the 2nd, and so on...). But, of course, you can use any array you want.